Using the Cloud Identity Devices API in Google Apps Script
I am using the Cloud Identity Devices API to retrieve a list of devices from the "Company-owned inventory" using Google Apps Script.
The script:
function listDevices() {
 const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 const url = 'https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/devices';
 const options = {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
   },
   maxResults: 100,
   muteHttpExceptions: true
 };
 const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 Logger.log(json);
}

When I run the script and authenticate using super admin, I receive an error:

{error={code=403.0,
details=[{metadata={service=cloudidentity.googleapis.com,
method=google.apps.cloudidentity.devices.v1.DevicesService.GetDevice},
domain=googleapis.com, @type=type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo,
reason=ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT}], message=Request had
insufficient authentication scopes., status=PERMISSION_DENIED}}


The error indicates that there are "insufficient permissions to retrieve the data."
The user super admin has maximum rights.
I want to get a list of devices from "Company Owned Inventory" using a Google Apps script.
